# How to fetch contacts in iOS ONLY with name AND phone number both stored?

Tags: addressbook, xcode-6.2, ios8.2

I need to send SMS via my app to the contacts of my iPhone Address Book. In that, there are few contacts which are not saved with the names and few have only email ids. I need to fetch contacts only with name and phone numbers both. How can I do that? Any sample code will be helpful!